# Как Сектор donuta можна оставить выделеным(отодвинтым) при клике, а при повторном вернyть назад

Tags: javascript, d3.js, графики, c3.js

```js
/* global $ */
/* global d3 */
/* global c3 */
$(document).ready(function () {
  var chart1 = c3.generate({
    bindto: '#chart1',
    data: {
      columns: [
        ['Corp. Finance', 10],
        ['Marketing', 8],
        ['Other', 2]
      ],
      type: 'donut'
    },
    donut: {
      title: '800 h',
      label: {
        format: function (value, ratio, id) {
          return d3.format(',.1f')(value)
        }
      }
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/pubnub/eon/master/lib/eon.css"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/pubnub/eon/master/lib/eon.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.pubnub.com/pubnub-3.7.13.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart1"></div>
```

Comment: на голом д3 сделал бы, а с3 не понятно как кастомизировать :)